# How to write a modified line from a text file in a new text file

Tags: python, text-files

I've looked everywhere and I'm still having trouble writing a specified line from a file to a new file. If I have a file called test.txt with the following content:

```
Hello
World
This
Is
My
File
```

I want to write this file into a new file adding text to each line. Say I want the output to look like

```
First Hello
Second World
Third This
Fourth Is
Fifth My
Sixth File
```

My current code is

```
def addLines(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as fin:
        with open('test2.txt', 'w') as fout:
            for line in fout:
                fout.write('First')
                fout.write(line[0])
                fout.write('Second')
                fout.write(line[1])
                fout.write('Third')
                fout.write(line[2])
                fout.write('Fourth')
                fout.write(line[3])
                fout.write('Fifth')
                fout.write(line[4])
                fout.write('Sixth')
                fout.write(line[5])
    fout.close()
```

And yes I know it doesn't work. I'm just confused on what to do and that was my best guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a beginning, start with this:

```
def addLines(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as fin:
        with open('test2.txt', 'w') as fout:
            for line in fin:
                fout.write('First {0}'.format(line))
```

For counting lines, two approaches are feasable:

1. Based on the example above, works with any number of lines in your input file

   ```
           i = 1
           for line in fin:
               fout.write('Line #{0}: {1}'.format(i, line))
               i += 1
   ```
2. If you really want to have *first*, *second* and so on, its more complicated.
   You could create a dictionary with `numbers = {1: 'first', 2: 'second'}` and then write to the file like this:

   ```
               fout.write('{0} {1}'.format(numbers[i], line))
   ```